# How to include known parameter that changes over time in solve_bvp

Tags: python, scipy, differential-equations, numerical-integration

I am trying to use scipy's solve_bvp in python to solve differential equations that depend on a known parameter that changes over time. I have this parameter saved in a numpy array. However, when I try to use this array in the derivatives function, I get the following error `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10,) (11,)`.

Below is a simplified version of my code. I want the variable `d2` to take certain values at different times according to an array, `d2_set_values`. The differential equations for some of the 12 variables then depend on `d2`. I hope it's clear from this code what I'm trying to achieve.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import solve_bvp

t = np.linspace(0, 10, 11)

# Known parameter that changes over time
d2_set_values = np.zeros(t.size)
d2_set_values[:4] = 0.1
d2_set_values[4:8] = 0.2
d2_set_values[8:] = 0.1

# Initialise y vector
y = np.zeros((12, t.size))

# ODEs
def fun(x, y):
    S1, I1, R1, S2, I2, R2, lamS1, lamI1, lamR1, lamS2, lamI2, lamR2 = y
    
    d1 = 0.5*(I1 + 0.1*I2)*(lamS1 - lamI1)
    d2 = d2_set_values
    
    dS1dt = -0.5*S1*(1-d1)*(I1 + 0.1*I2)
    dS2dt = -0.5*S2*(1-d2)*(I2 + 0.1*I1)
    dI1dt = 0.5*S1*(1-d1)*(I1 + 0.1*I2) - 0.2*I1
    dI2dt = 0.5*S2*(1-d2)*(I2 + 0.1*I1) - 0.2*I2
    dR1dt = 0.2*I1
    dR2dt = 0.2*I2
    dlamS1dt = 0.5*(1-d1)*S1*lamS1
    dlamS2dt = 0.5*(1-d2)*S2*lamS2
    dlamI1dt = 0.5*(1-d1)*I1*lamI1
    dlamI2dt = 0.5*(1-d2)*I2*lamI2
    dlamR1dt = lamR1
    dlamR2dt = lamR2
    
    return np.vstack((dS1dt, dI1dt, dR1dt, dS2dt, dI2dt, dR2dt, dlamS1dt, dlamI1dt, dlamR1dt, dlamS2dt, dlamI2dt, dlamR2dt))

# Boundary conditions
def bc(ya, yb):
    return np.array([ya[0]-0.99, ya[1]-0.01, ya[2]-0., ya[3]-1.0, ya[4]-0., ya[5]-0., 
                     yb[6]-0., yb[7]-1., yb[8]-0., yb[9]-0, yb[10]-0, yb[11]-0])

# Run the solver
sol = solve_bvp(fun, bc, t, y)
```

I have even tried reducing the size of `d2_set_values` by one, but that doesn't solve the issue.

Any help I can get would be much appreciated!

Comment: You need to interpolate `d2`. Use for instance `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` to generate an interpolation function.

Comment: Thanks so much! That did the trick :)